# pygame - import error: no module named freetype

Tags: python, python-2.7, gcc, pygame

I'm trying working on a little project, in which I would need to get to work freetype.
But all what I got are errors.

```
slu-suse:~/Systemthegame # python main-noclick.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main-noclick.py", line 204, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': menu()
  File "main-noclick.py", line 6, in menu
    import pygame, pygame.freetype
ImportError: No module named freetype
```

I did tried to reinstall pygame, but I got gcc error 1 which failed after including Python.h.
But I don't get it, because 'whereis Python.h' returned 'Python:'

I'm on openSUSE if that helps.

Comment: Maybe you need to install python packet `FreeType` using `pip` and/or openSUSE `FreeType` packet using `yast`/`rpm`/`tarball`. BTW: `Python.h` should be in `python-dev` packet.

Comment: Thanks. I installed FreeType with zypper(pack. manager for suse), but FreeType for python I guess does not exist - pip and easy_install didn't found it. Also, zypper doesn't have python-dev packet. So my problem is still unsolved.

Comment: I use Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu/Debian) and I have `FreeType` in `pip` (but I didn't try to install it) and in `apt` (my packet manager). After system reinstallation I didn't reinstall `pygame` and I don't know whether freetype installation can help.

Comment: For reference, Fedora 20 has a package `python-freetype`.